# How to start next Activity?

Tags: java, android, cordova

i would like to in my Android application uses a listview once an item clicked on the list it will go to next Activity.But in next Activity i have used cordova-2.0.0 jar file for phone gap;When i run the application its getting NoClassdefFoundError on itemClickListnere.Can someone help me please. Thanks.

Here is My Code.
 public class Learn_Screen extends Activity
        {
            ListView chapter_ListView;

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.learn);
            chapter_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            String strChapter_Content = adapter.getItem(position);
                            System.out.println("strChapter_Content = " + strChapter_Content);
                            Intent i = new Intent(Learn_Screen.this , Chapter_Detail.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();



                        }
                    });
    }
```

Here is Another Activity code.

```
public class Chapter_Detail extends DroidGap
    {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/chapter_one.html", 10000);
        }

    }
```

Here is my LogCat Info.

```
 09-15 13:51:45.976: W/dalvikvm(1149): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/test_application/Chapter_Detail; (1274)
    09-15 13:51:45.976: W/dalvikvm(1149): Link of class 'Lcom/test_application/Chapter_Detail;' failed
    09-15 13:51:45.976: E/dalvikvm(1149): Could not find class 'com.test_application.Chapter_Detail', referenced from method com.test_application.Learn_Screen$1.onItemClick
    09-15 13:51:45.983: W/dalvikvm(1149): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1143 (Lcom/test_application/Chapter_Detail;) in Lcom/test_application/Learn_Screen$1;
    09-15 13:51:45.983: D/dalvikvm(1149): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0020
    09-15 13:51:45.983: D/dalvikvm(1149): VFY: dead code 0x0022-002f in Lcom/test_application/Learn_Screen$1;.onItemClick (Landroid/widget/AdapterView;Landroid/view/View;IJ)V
    09-15 13:51:48.072: I/System.out(1149): strChapter_Content = OOPs concepts
    09-15 13:51:48.072: D/AndroidRuntime(1149): Shutting down VM
    09-15 13:51:48.082: W/dalvikvm(1149): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test_application.Chapter_Detail
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.test_application.Learn_Screen$1.onItemClick(Learn_Screen.java:100)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    09-15 13:51:48.112: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my Menifest lil enfo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test_application"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test_application.Splash_Acreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.test_application.Setting_Screen"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.test_application.Learn_Screen"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.test_application.Chapter_Detail"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Show your manifest file.

Comment: Show your manifest file.

Comment: @Dhruti & raj : - above i have add menifest.xl file

Comment: @Dhruti : I have changes in my app but right now here is another error 09-15 14:25:24.372: E/PluginManager(1254): ERROR: plugin.xml is missing.  Add res/xml/plugins.xml to your project.
09-15 14:25:24.372: E/PluginManager(1254): https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/res/xml/plugins.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got this error  when
You did not copy the cordova.jar to the libs directory directly but to libs/phonegap-phonegap-ce32a3f/lib/android/cordova.jar

So keep in mind: ALWAYS copy jars into the root of libs folder!

also dont forget to mention it in menifest file.

Comment: :-I have changes in my app but right now here is another 09-15 14:25:24.372: E/PluginManager(1254): ERROR: plugin.xml is missing.  Add res/xml/plugins.xml to your project.
09-15 14:25:24.372: E/PluginManager(1254): https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/res/xml/plugins.xml

Comment: you have to add a plugins.xml file in res/xml/ directory

Comment: and copy config file from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try extending from `CordovaActivity` instead of `DroidGap`. Are you sure you've properly added the library to the project (if you're using ADT, then add to /libs and also checked Order and Export in the build path).